# Checking an XElement for Existence of One of Several Possible XElements

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml, xelement

Is there a way to determine if an XElement contains one of any specified elements? For example, I have XElements that I'll want to check:

```
Dim xe1 = <color><blue/></color>
Dim xe2 = <color><red/></color>
Dim xe3 = <color><powderBlue/></color>
Dim xe4 = <color><aqua/></color>
Dim xe5 = <color><green/></color>
```

I'd like to be able to query any of the xelements to see if they containt the elements `<red/>`, `<green/>` or `<blue/>` below them and return true if so, false if not.

I was hoping that it would be simplier, but the best I could come up with was:

```
Dim primaryColor = From e In xe1.Elements Where e.Name = "blue" Or e.Name = "red" Or e.Name = "green"
Dim primaryColorTrue = primaryColor.SingleorDefault
If primaryColorTrue IsNot Nothing Then
'Blah
End If
```

Does anyone have a better way to do this, such as putting those xelements of red/green/blue into an array and using something like Elements.Contains(list of elements)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly - perhaps (using C#, sorry - but no real C# specific logic here):

```
var colors = new[] {"red", "green","blue"};
bool any = el.Descendants().Any(child => colors.Contains(child.Name.LocalName));
```

Even if the VB fights you, I'm sure you can use `.Any` instead of `.SingleOrDefault` and a `null` check.

For info, using **elements** here to me sounds like an odd idea; I'd just have the color name as the *text* if possible:

```
<somexml><color>blue</color></somexml>
```

or even as an attribute:

```
<somexml color="blue"/>
```

Comment: Funny stuff- I didn't like your original answer, so I coded up a solution I thought was better, refreshed the page, and you had the same solution as me! So +1.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you! Here it is in VB -         Dim colors() = New String() {"green", "blue", "red"}
        Dim any As Boolean = el.Descendants.Any(Function(e) colors.Contains(e.Name.LocalName))

Comment: Yeah, the thing-a-muh-jig with using elements was just a sample of querying for children elements that may or may not exist. The XML files are not mine, so I can't change those.