# Function Contains in XElement

Tags: c#-3.0

How do I get if the XElement Contains Specific children ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`HasElements`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.haselements.aspx) or [`HasAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.hasattributes.aspx).

If you want to check for a specific set of elements, look here: 
 [Checking an XElement for Existence of One of Several Possible XElements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805475/checking-an-xelement-for-existence-of-one-of-several-possible-xelements/1805493#1805493)